# Highstock : Multiple area range

Tags: highcharts

I search to display multiple range depends average, see this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/josse34/5gjne/12/

rangesgreen is calculate -20% and +20% of theorical averages - 
rangesred is defined with minimum of rangesgreen and averages - 
rangesblue is defined with maximum of rangesgreen and averages

rangesblue is destined to show the area when average is up of rangesgreen - 
rangesred is destined to show the area when average is down of rangesgreen

As well, into this jsfiddle, area is blue (it's correct) the 4 July of 2009 but area must be red the 3 July of 2009.
I don't know how to correct this problem, the setting of

```
                zIndex: [number],
```

is not enought!

Thanks for helping!

Comment: do you want the chart be blue above the green area and red below the green area is that correct????

Comment: Exactly! When averages is below the greeen range, i would like the Red range and blue range above!

Comment: As I see red and blue has the same data, so how it should be indexed? because when I modified zindex (i.e) red to higher, then is dislpayed correct.

Comment: Hi Sebastian. I can put inside data of ranges blues and red what you want for display correctly, as well averages, minimum, maximum or medium of green ranges. It's not very important, the most important is to display correctly red range when averages is below green range and blue range when averages is above green ranges, do you understand? Thanks!!!!

Comment: So, i explain not very well, i would like this display :
     
http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/466406high.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: It is imporssible, because when you have red area and blue are with the same data, you cannot set partly index. Maybe threshold will be helpful like here: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.threshold

Comment: I don't understand how to use threshold, could you give me a exemple by updating my jsfiddle?? Thanks!

Comment: Hi!Ok i understand treshold, but it's possible to do not have a fix treshold but dynamic into json data like for http://jsfiddle.net/josse34/5gjne/12/    [1246492800000, 18, 20],??

Comment: Nice support for premium customers...